# Creating a new object with it's own unique name

Tags: java, javafx

I want a button that will create a new object (in this case being a textfield) but the example could be any object. When you press the button, it will create the object with its own name, like a box that will say "box1" and the next "box2" and so on. That way you can reference them later by their name.

Anybody have any links to read up on this or any similar questions? I think I just don't know the right word for it because I couldn't find anything.

Comment: You mean setting the ID of the object?

Comment: add components dynamically? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35490113/995891

Comment: `private int nextId = 1; private Box createBox() { int id = nextId++; return new Box("box" + id); }`?

Comment: You cannot reference dynamically create new fields in a class. You could however use some suitable data structure such as `Map<String, Node>` (if you want to access the values using strings) or a `List<Node>` (if you want to access them via ints 0, ..., n)